# UTC to EST SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, dst

We have data in SQL Server 2008, with multiple date time columns. As date format in SQL Server is a big integer value i.e. number of seconds since 1970, we are using `DATEADD()` function to convert it into actual date time format. But the issue we are facing is that when we use DATEADD(), we get data in UTC timezone whereas we want data in EST. I tried simply using -4 HR from the time but during NOV - MAR we are 1 HR ahead because the difference is 5 HR when daylight time is off. Is there any function that can be used which considers daylight saving time. Any help is appreciated.

```
Current Function -> DATEADD(s, columnName, '01/01/1970 00:00:00')
```

Regards, Sahil

Comment: There isn't anything native. This is incredibly difficult. The dates for daylight saving time has changed over the years. Some states do not recognize daylight saving time. Not even the entire state of Arizona recognizes daylight saving time. And that is only the complication in the US. Once you go outside those borders it gets even more complicated.

Comment: There are whole libraries that are written strictly to deal with Dates / Times (*like NodaTime, Momentjs, etc*) but non for Sql Server that I know of as this is generally addressed in the application layer, not the persistence layer.

Comment: You can import an assembly that wraps the TimeZoneInfo class and reads from the windows registry values for time zone offsets (same way windows does it). These values get sporadic updates as you apply windows updates. Time zone information not only changes on a scheduled (DST or whatever) basis but also changes on a ad-hoc basis as regions and countries see fit. I would use a tested library and import that into sql server.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), columnName)
```

Comment: This only works if we want the time conversion to be in the current time -- i.e. if it's currently daylight savings or not.  I believe the OP has datetimes around the year and needs to convert from UTC to EST based on the date of the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project for this.  It uses IANA standard time zone names, [as listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Building on your example, the following first converts from a UNIX Timestamp to a UTC based `datetime`, then converts to a `datetime` in the US Eastern time zone.

```
SELECT Tzdb.UtcToLocal(DATEADD(s, columnName, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 'America/New_York')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would write a UDF that interacts with a time database such as the one from worldtimeserver.com -- I'm not affiliated with them and have found it with a quick internet search.

Further research shows timezonedb.com which has a free (if non-commercial) membership, allows to download the database and has examples on how to use with SQL Server and MySQL.